# Flip the landscape orientation in Android?

Tags: android, andengine

In AndEngine you have the ability to set the screens orientation for the game or project.

In my project the Landscape orientation is the wrong way. It is basically upside down for the project i need.

Is there anyway to rotate the scene in AndEngine or in android to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the android SDK .....  I use this code to set my app to Portrait (as opposed to Landscape):

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```